# Three.js error when applying texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

Hi I am writing a web application using three.js and JavaScript and everything was working fine until I have tried my application on  the chrome for android.

The application is giving an error concerning the texture i.e

`ERROR: THREE.WebGLRenderer: S3TC compressed textures not supported`.

Can anyone please help me solve this.
Texture code:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
    loader.load(texturePath, function (image) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.transparent = true;
```

Comment: Googling "S3TC compressed texture" leads you to opengl.org where you find this: "S3TC is a technique for compressing images for use as textures. Standard image compression techniques like JPEG and PNG can achieve greater compression ratios than S3TC. However, S3TC is designed to be implemented in high-performance hardware. JPEG and PNG decompress images all-at-once, while S3TC allows specific sections of the image to be decompressed independently." So it seems you are using an image format not covered by Chrome/Android. Have you tried vanilla JPG?

Comment: i am using a normal jpg file

Comment: Wikipedia talks about licensing issues, so that might even explain Chrome gap?

Comment: What you have posted as an ERROR is only a console.log from Three.js, indicating that the HW that you are running on (ie, the GL implementation), does not support S3TC compressed extension. This is relevant only if your texture is using such a compression. But you indicated you are using only a JPG file hence it is not related to whatever issue you are facing.

What is the actual error that you are seeing - ie, does the image not show up on screen ? Is there an artifact ?

Comment: I havae manged by converting my texture to png